# What does “s/it” mean in Keras training output?

Tags: keras

I searched in google to find out what s/it mean in

```
11%|█         | 25/230 [19:46:11<124:54:52, 2193.62s/it]
```

But couldn't find any solution. My guess is seconds required per iterations? Is having higher s/it good?

Comment: seconds/iteration

Comment: Having higher seconds/iteration means each iteration takes more time to complete. So, what do you think, is it good?

Comment: @desertnaut Thank you. I was in doubt whether it meant something else, like samples(training samples) per iterations.